# gets function is causing an Invalid argument error

Tags: ruby

I'm having to learn ruby (not rails) due to a device that only runs ruby installed code.

I'm currently using v 1.9.3 on my Windows 10 desktop to study the syntax and I can't run any examples with the gets() function.

example:

```
name = gets()
```

without getting the error

> test.rb:1:in `gets': Invalid argument -  (Errno::EINVAL)

I haven't tried updating the version (Manufacturer's guide, though possible just out of date, listed installing 1.9) but I wouldn't think such a core function would be missing from this version.

puts() works just fine.

Thanks in advance for any direction...

Comment: That should work, but keep in mind Ruby 1.9.3 is extraordinarily out of date. If you can, pull down the latest, currently 2.6.5, and use that. One thing to note with Ruby is empty argument lists are omitted, so that's just `gets` and not `gets()`.

Comment: I asked my grandfather, who used to use v1.9.2 and he said it should work, that `gets()` was the same as `gets` even way back then.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Either way works when you're using a typewriter.

Comment: Thanks @tadman and carey-swoveland.  Unfortunately I am stuck using 1.9.3 because that is what the Manufacturer has installed on the device. I did try "gets" and "gets()" and I get the same error for each.

Comment: If something as simple as `gets` doesn't work that suggests that Ruby installation is fundamentally broken. It may have been compiled for an earlier version of Windows.

Comment: @anothermh, you misjudge my age. I was referring to the printing press.

Comment: How are you executing the file (IDE, cmd.exe, etc.)? Does your path (including your username) contain any notable character (emoji, kanji, etc.)?

Comment: I installed by running the Ruby Installer, which seems to just extract to c:\Ruby193. I've tried both running the interactive as well as ruby at the dos command prompt.  I reran the installer being sure that the directory was added to the Path.

Comment: I installed a later 1.9.3 package p.551 and it appears to have solved my problem.